# Crystal report display incorrect character while using Oracle Database connection

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle11g

I am trying to create a simple report on Crystal Report 10. This report will pull data from Oracle database.
I have installed Oracle 11g (32 bit) client on my PC.  To connect to Oracle database we only have to use Oracle connection (i.e. using crdb_oracle.dll)
My PC has windows 7 64 bit version.

When i pull data from oracle server on crystal report 10 is changes to different character format.

The actual character should be as

> "**ç Abcxyz("ç")**."

But on crystal report it shows as *

> c Abcxyz("c").*

I have searched everywhere on Web but i didn't find any solution.  It would be grateful if anyone can please provide the solution for this problem.

Comment: This is often an issue of the diver used by the data connector. What driver are you using?

Comment: Hi Campagnolo_1,  I am using crdb_oracle.dll for connecting to Oracle database server.

Comment: Try using an ODBC or OLEDB connector and see if you get the same issue. If you don't, then your connector driver needs updating

Comment: Hi Campagnolo_1    I have used ODBC connection it works fine. The font/character pulls exactly what it should be.   But when i connect to oracle directly using Crystal report using crbc_Oracle.dll it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is not because of crystal report.one way is change the `NLS_LANG` of oracle in windows `regedit`in this path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE` and find all the NLS_LANG which are available there and then change all of them to something which suitable for your language.

Comment: Thanks Hamidreza.  I tried changing the NLS_LANG to Brazil i.e. "BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252".  As the above character is from brazil language.  But it didn't changed, Please advise me if i am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the characters come over correctly using the ODBC (see comments in original question), you could just use ODBC. If that is for some reason not an option, then I suggest updating your Oracle driver with the latest version. 
One more suggestion: Make sure you have the latest service packs for CR installed!